# iOS - UIAlertView being dismissed before expected

Tags: objective-c, ios, multithreading, uialertview, dispatcher

I have a view and, among other things, a button on it. When the user pushes the button, the following code is executed:

```
- (IBAction) goToPhotoViewControllerView:(id) sender{

    alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Por favor, aguarde" message:@"Carregando imagens" 
                                  delegate:nil 
                         cancelButtonTitle:nil 
                         otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];

    if(alert != nil) {
        UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];

        indicator.center = CGPointMake(alert.bounds.size.width/2, alert.bounds.size.height-45);
        [indicator startAnimating];
        [alert addSubview:indicator];
        [indicator release];
    }

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{

    //Do a lot of stuff here

        PhotoViewController *photoViewControllerView = [[PhotoViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PhotoViewController" bundle:nil];

        [iosDao selectComics];

        [photoViewControllerView startWithComic:[[iosDao.comics lastObject] idComic] numPanels:[[[iosDao.comics lastObject] panels] count]];
        photoViewControllerView.navigationItem.title = @"Comics";

        [iosDao release];
        [[self navigationController] pushViewController:photoViewControllerView animated:YES];

        [alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
        [alert release];
    });
}
```

What happens is that, most of the time, the whole asynchronous code runs, dismissing the alert message. However, after the alert message is dismissed, the screen still stays frozen for about 2 or 3 seconds before it pushes to the next viewController (photoViewControllerView). I have no idea why that is happening. I want the alert message to stay on as long as needed. Any ideas?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

So to me, it sounds like the problem is the PhotoViewController is taking time to load (can you use Instruments to confirm?). Since PhotoViewController is your own class, you could have it have a delegate, make the main view controller (the one that dismisses the UIAlert) the delegate of PhotoViewController instance, and have the PhotoViewController call the delegate to inform it when it's ready and/or visible, for example at the end of

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

Comment: Humm, that makes sense. But let me ask you. Does that mean that the PhotoViewController is being allocated asynchronously? I mean, shouldn'd the last two lines (the ones with the alert dismiss and release) be reached just AFTER the PhotoViewController is completed loaded (once this last one is in the middle of the code, way before the alert dismiss)?

Comment: I tried what you said and it didn`t work. I put the dismiss line as the last line of the PhotoViewController`s viewWillAppear method. What is driving me crazy, however, is that it reaches that line, dismiss the alert (as expected) and then, after that, it freezes the screen for about 3 or 4 seconds before actually move to the PhotoViewController view. I thought that as soon as the last line of the viewWillAppear is reached, the new view would have to appear RIGHT AFTER that. But it doesn`t. The previous view freezes for about 2 or 3 seconds before move. Does anybody have any clue why?

Answer (score 1):

You should just present an alert view and assign self as it's delegate, then when you get informed that alert view is dismissed (via [alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertViewDelegate_Protocol/UIAlertViewDelegate/UIAlertViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIAlertViewDelegate/alertView%3adidDismissWithButtonIndex%3a) delegate method), execute the rest of your code.

Comment: Hi fichek. Thanks for replying. What I want to do is to execute all of the asynchronous part BEFORE the alertView is dismissed. I want the alertView to stay on as long as necessary for the asynchronous code to run and, just then, switch viewControllers.

Comment: Oh, just noticed your alert view has no buttons and you want it to dismiss programmatically only. That's a bad way to tell people to wait. UIActivityIndicatorView and a label would do just fine.